# Proving that the set of all $n\times n$ upper Hessenberg matrices forms a vector space

Tags: vector-spaces

To prove a set is a vector space, we need to show the following properties hold: (here $a$ and $b$ are real values, $v$ and $w$ are $n\times 1$ vectors, and $n\geq 2$): 
$$v+w=w+v$$
$$a(b*w)=(ab)*w$$
$$ 1*w=w$$
$$a(v+w)=av+aw$$
$$(a+b)w=aw+bw.$$

But the above equations seem trivially true for all the matrices. I guess there must be something that I misunderstand. Could anybody help?

Comment: Did you mean Heisenberg?

Comment: Also you shall show that $v + w, aw$ are all **well-defined** in this vector space.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing two important properties: closure of scalar multiplication and vector addition:
$$av \in V$$
$$v+w\in V$$
for any scalar $a$ and vectors $v,w\in V$. You will need to show these additional properties hold in order to prove that Hessenberg matrices are a vector space (they're "obviously" true, but unlike the other properties you listed, you do not inherit them for free from the algebraic properties that all matrices share.)